# Is there a way to comment out a large chunk of code?

Tags: emacs, comments

I'm trying to comment out a large piece of code in a program but it's too difficult to do it manually. Is there a program to do it for me? (making such program doesn't seem hard anyway)
Also, I'm using emacs. Does emacs have such a function? (or an emacs Lisp file at least?)

Comment: You have some custom functions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041904/eclipse-like-line-commenting-in-emacs/20045679#20045679

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In emacs, you can use `M-x comment-region` and `M-x uncomment-region`.

Comment: Also, you can use `M-;` to toggle the commentedness of the current region, but only if the region is active. I always just do it "by hand" with the above commands.

Comment: That shortcut is amazing!

Comment: `M-;` works well together with `region-expand.el`, for example when you want to comment out a function: https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el

Comment: For newcomers: Hold `Alt` pressed and then press `;`, this can comment and uncomment the selected region.

Comment: @questionto42 Also for newcomers: it's worth reading the tutorial that comes with emacs for e.g. the description of the keyboard notation and basic commands

Comment: @user234461 Before these two hints get overseen in the comments, I made them an answer.

Answer (score 35):

The `comment-region` method bound to key `M-;`. You can select region using marker and then use `M-;` to comment/uncomment.

Comment: For beginners selecting the region with the marker can be done by: C-SPACE and then moving the marker with the Super and Meta keys. (Moving the cursor/marker is the first thing that the Emacs tutorial teaches. It is a good idea to learn that.)

Answer (score 0):

You can mark at the beginning of the region that you want to comment out, move to the end of the region, then do C-c C-c or M-x comment-region.

Comment: in which mode does "C-c C-c" == "M-x comment-region"? just curious

Comment: @Tom I had though it works generally, but after you pointed out, I tested; it works with ruby-mode, but does not seem to work in (some) other modes. Help says it is bound to `comment-region` defined in `newcomment.el`.

Comment: ah good to know. I hack python so I went and looked it up and in python-mode it executes the region. :)

Comment: "C-c C-c **(in C-like modes)**

    Add comment delimiters to all the lines in the region. " --- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Comment-Commands.html

Answer (score 0):

I bind `comment-region` to `C-M-;`.  And remember that `C-u` uncomments the commented region.

E.g. `C-u 2 C-M-;` comments the region with `;;` (in Lisp). Then `C-u C-M-;` uncomments the region.  (The region must be active in both cases.)

Answer (score -1):

Taking up two comments of the accepted answer, this is just another key binding on top of it:

For newcomers: hold `Alt` pressed and then press `;`, this can comment and uncomment the selected region.

And also for newcomers: "it's worth reading the tutorial that comes with emacs for e.g. the description of the keyboard notation and basic commands."