# Eclipse-like Line Commenting in Emacs

Tags: eclipse, emacs, comments, elisp

In Eclipse, highlighting multiple rows and pressing <kbd>Ctrl+/</kbd> comments each of the lines of the selection.

Emacs has a function `comment-or-uncomment-region` that is close what I want, but behaves differently if the region only partially covers the lines I'm trying to comment.

Is there any way I make a function similar to `comment-or-uncomment-region`, but have it comment each of the lines of the region regardless of how the region is selected?

In other words, I want the function to act as though the region occupies the whole line as long as the region includes that line, so it behaves as Eclipse's selection commenting does.

**EDIT:** I am actually using the `comment-or-uncomment-region-or-line` function mentioned as an answer instead of the function `comment-or-uncomment-region` that comes with Emacs.

I feel as though this is worth mentioning because the former seems to reflect how the line commenting works in Eclipse more.  That is, the line the point is on is commented if no region exists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up combining parts from **juanleon**'s and **Ehvince**'s answers to get something just a little more like Eclipse's commenting.

Here is the final product:

```
(defun comment-eclipse ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((start (line-beginning-position))
        (end (line-end-position)))
    (when (or (not transient-mark-mode) (region-active-p))
      (setq start (save-excursion
                    (goto-char (region-beginning))
                    (beginning-of-line)
                    (point))
            end (save-excursion
                  (goto-char (region-end))
                  (end-of-line)
                  (point))))
    (comment-or-uncomment-region start end)))
```

Please let me know if anything is wrong with it.

Comment: This function is ok for users of transient-mark-mode.  It won't work for users of "old-style regions".  If you change the condition by `(or (not transient-mark-mode) (region-active-p))` function will be ok for both kinds of users.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! And I wasn't aware of transient-mark-mode being a more contemporary thing.

Answer (score 6):

Note that emacs 25 has a new function `comment-line` bound to `C-x C-;`.

Comment: @RickyRobinson Emacs 25 is due in the next few weeks, if not days :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a function that do what you are describing:

```
(defun comment-or-uncomment-region-eclipse-style (beg end &optional arg)
  (interactive "*r\nP")
  (comment-or-uncomment-region
   (save-excursion
     (goto-char beg)
     (beginning-of-line)
     (point))
   (save-excursion
     (goto-char end)
     (end-of-line)
     (point)) arg))
```

Comment: This works, but I experience an unexpected side-effect.  When I execute the command again, the rows from the previous region are all uncommented.  Additionally, moving the point and executing the command again will comment/uncomment from the row the region started on to the point.  Is there a way to change behavior if there is no region selected, such as only commenting the current line?  I will try to look at the `comment-or-uncomment-region-or-line` mentioned elsewhere for a guide in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I don't use `comment-or-uncomment-region`.  I use **`comment-region`** instead.  It's similar, but it lets *you* decide whether to uncomment or comment.  It lets you nest comments, instead of automatically uncommenting the region if it is already commented out.  With a numeric prefix arg it uses that many comment-start chars (e.g., `;`, `;;`, `;;;`,... in Lisp).  With a plain `C-u` prefix arg it uncomments.  I bind it to `C-x C-;`.

Anyway, I think this does what you want, using `comment-region` (see that for the general behavior):

```
(defun comment-region-lines (beg end &optional arg)
  "Like `comment-region', but comment/uncomment whole lines."
  (interactive "*r\nP")
  (if (> beg end) (let (mid) (setq mid beg beg end end mid)))
  (let ((bol  (save-excursion (goto-char beg) (line-beginning-position)))
        (eol  (save-excursion (goto-char end) (line-end-position))))
    (comment-region bol end arg)))

;; Suggested binding
(define-key ctl-x-map [(control ?\;)] 'comment-region-lines)
```

This saves and restores the region.  And it works if only part of a single line is selected.  I might even use it myself (which is saying quite a bit, since I have pretty set habits for this kind of thing).

Answer (score 0):

Compared to Juanleon's solution, mine adds the fact that if you don't select a region it will (un)comment the current line and go the next line (instead of doing something based on marks you don't see):

```
  (defun comment-or-uncomment-region-or-line ()
"Comments or uncomments the region or the current line if there's no active region."
(interactive)
(let (beg end)
    (if (region-active-p)
        (setq beg (region-beginning) end (region-end))
        (setq beg (line-beginning-position) end (line-end-position)))
    (comment-or-uncomment-region beg end)
    (next-line)))
;; bind it to F7:
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>")'comment-or-uncomment-region-or-line)
```

taken from: [Emacs comment/uncomment current line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688748/emacs-comment-uncomment-current-line)

Comment: I neglected to mention that I am actually using this function rather than the `comment-or-uncomment-region` that comes with Emacs.  The behavior I want to avoid still happens with this, in that it won't comment the way I wan't if I don't select entire lines.

Comment: I'm using evil-mode so I don't have your pb: to select a region line by line I press "V" (instead of simple "v" char by char).

Answer (score 0):

There is a file which provides the following

```
(defun ar-comment-or-uncomment-lor (&optional copy beg end)
  "Comment line or region, unless it's already commented:
uncomment then.
```

..." 
    ...

Afterwards cursor is at next line, which permits repeated execution.

With <kbd>C-u</kbd> the current line is copied and inserted as comment above - thus reminding the previous state when editing.

Get it here:

https://github.com/andreas-roehler/werkstatt/blob/master/ar-comment-lor.el

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight change to Ehvince's function which only advances to the next line if text was commented out. i.e., if uncommenting text, you usually want the cursor to remain.

```
(defun comment-or-uncomment-region-or-line ()
  "Comments or uncomments the region or the current line if there's no active region."
  (interactive)
  (let (beg end)
    (if (region-active-p)
        (setq beg (region-beginning) end (region-end))
      (setq beg (line-beginning-position) end (line-end-position)))
    (comment-or-uncomment-region beg end)
    (when (comment-only-p beg end)
        (next-logical-line))))
```